# Nextcloud like software to sync contacts ONLY

Tags: raspberry-pi, synchronization, nextcloud

I'm using Nextcloud on a Raspberry Pi 4 server, but only to save and sync contacts.
But for the use I have of it, Nextcloud is very heavy...
Wouldn't there be a lighter software to back up the contacts on my phone (with Davx5 or equivalent)?
Thanks

Comment: This raises the question why, if you already operate a nextcloud instance, you do not use it for other things as well ...

Comment: I am sure Google _loves_ to sync all your contacts between all your devices ;-)

Comment: @arkascha Thanks, but I'm not using Google (custom ROM...). And I don't use Nextcloud for others things because it's too slow on my rpi, and don't need it, Syncthing is enough... And what about my question ?

Comment: I also use a custom ROM on my mobile devices. That does not mean that you cannot use Google, though. You might not want to, sure, makes sense.

Comment: I am not aware of any specific tool for this. There are many file based synchronization approches, but that does not integrate with how Android handles contacts. Instead you could try a generic WebDav service for this. I never tried myself, but that should be possible. There is "mod_dav" for example, a well known apache module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baikal seems to be a good alternative :
https://sabre.io/baikal/